# Interface timeout when calling WebService

Tags: java, apache-axis

I use Axis1.4, the Java language, to call the interface of the other party's system. After sending the request according to the normal steps, I always hold a timeout, and I even set the timeout time. I have checked other addresses several times, but I don't know why I keep reporting this error.

```
AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException
 faultSubcode:
 faultString: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
 faultActor:
 faultNode:
 faultDetail:
        {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265)
        at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.readHeadersFromSocket(HTTPSender.java:583)
        at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(HTTPSender.java:143)
        at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
        at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
        at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
        at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:165)
        at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
        at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
        at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
        at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
        at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
        at clinicalpath.hy.client.PlsZyyClientZy.SearchZyzd(PlsZyyClientZy.java:95)
        at clinicalpath.hy.service.drgs.impl.DrgsZyServiceImpl.getemrzdList(DrgsZyServiceImpl.java:95)
        at clinicalpath.hy.service.drgs.impl.DrgsZyServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$d95e12c2.invoke(&lt;generated&gt;)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:684)
        at clinicalpath.hy.service.drgs.impl.DrgsZyServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ab23513e.getemrzdList(&lt;generated&gt;)
```

I tried to set a timeout of 1 minute or 2 minutes for him, but it didn't work at all. Do I think it's a request for protocol type or any other issue?

Comment: how did you set timeout that did not work? can you give me the code snippet?

Comment: call.setTimeout(new Integer(60000));

Comment: its okay, Make sure this line of code is placed appropriately in your application, specifically before making the actual SOAP call.

Keep in mind that this timeout setting is for the entire SOAP call, including both the connection establishment and the time it takes to read the response. If the operation you are calling takes longer than the specified timeout, it will result in a SocketTimeoutException.